# How to continuously refresh data in a Snowflake table when using Snowpipe auto-ingest from S3 i.e. load new and drop old data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Created a Snowpipe which auto-ingests files in S3, as per [1]. Files are continuously put in the S3 bucket and the automated Snowpipe loads data into a Snowflake table.

As per [2], the S3 bucket has a lifecycle rule that deletes old files. However, it seems the Snowpipe appends to the Snowflake table rather than overwrite; even though the files are deleted from S3.

I would like to drop data from the Snowflake table when files are deleted within S3. Is there an elegant solution to do this with Snowpipe or within Snowflake?

P.S. I could find similar questions asked but no answers. Please direct me to an answer if it exists. Thanks

References:
[1] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html
[2] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-manage.html

Comment: what you are describing is like a INSERT OVERWRITE (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html) but Snowpipe uses the COPY INTO command, which is more like a vanilla INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Snowpipe is purely a tool for loading data; it loads staged data into a target table with no update/merge logic available. If you need to apply logic to your data before it's loaded, you could load the data into a staging table first and then insert/update/merge the data into the target table.